# Probability that the sum of 4 thrown dice equals $24$

Tags: probability

> Suppose we throw 4 dice consecutively. What is the probability
>   that the sum of the dice is $24?$

**My attempt**:

The experiment we consider is throwing 4 dices and looking at the numbers we obtain, i.e. $\Omega := \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}^4$

Define $$X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}: (\omega_1, \dots, \omega_4) \mapsto \sum_1^4\omega_i.$$

Then, $$\mathbb{P}(X = 24) = \mathbb{P}\left(\left\{(6,6,6,6)\right\}\right),$$

and assuming that every combination that can be thrown is as likely as the others, this is equal to $\left(\frac16\right)^4$. Is this the correct way to handle such problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your approach is correct.

The only way to get a sum of $24$ is having four $6$.

The probability of four independent event where each has the probability of $1/6$ is  $ 1/6^4$

Comment: About what 4 independent events are you talking? We are working in the space $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}^4$

Comment: @Math_QED The values of $\omega_i$, and the probability for each of those values, is independent of the other $\omega_j$'s.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your approach is correct.

In general, for other target sum, we can use generating function to solve the problem.